# Fixing same indentation of entries in List of Algorithms as other List of

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, algorithm2e

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{A}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{test}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{test}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

the entries in the List of Algorithms are indented, whereas the entries in List of Figures are nicely aligned with the chapter title.

[image]
[image]

How do I fix so that the entries in the LoA also align with the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entries in LoA should have the same indent and number width as the entries in LoF, you use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@algocf{\l@figure}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[algochapter]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@algocf{\l@figure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{A}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{test}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{test}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

List of algorithms is defined as List of figures in article, report and book class. That is memoir class that changes the indent of list of figures. 
So the answer given is the solution. 
I will include a command in next release to do that.